# Elasticsearch - Doesn't match multiwords synonyms exactly

Tags: elasticsearch, search-multiple-words

I'm trying to implement **the synonym filter** in order to have a more accurate search engine for my project.

I indexed a document which contain the words "**contrat à durée déterminée**". What I want is that all documents containing the **exact words** "**contrat à durée déterminée**" match when I search for the acronym "**cdd**".

Here is my index settings :

```
'analysis' => array(
    'analyzer' => array(
        'indexAnalyzer' => array(
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'nGram',
            'filter' => array('asciifolding', 'lowercase', 'synonym', 'snowball', 'elision', 'worddelimiter', 'stopwords'),
        ),
        'searchAnalyzer' => array(
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
            'filter' => array('asciifolding', 'lowercase', 'elision', 'worddelimiter', 'synonym', 'stopwords'),
        ),
        'rawAnalyzer' => array(
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
            'filter' => array('lowercase', 'trim'),
        ),
        'exactSearchAnalyzer' => array(
            'type' => 'custom',
            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
            'filter' => array('elision'),
        ),
    ),
    'tokenizer' => array(
        'nGram' => array(
            'type' => 'nGram',
            'min_gram' => 3,
            'max_gram' => 20,
            'token_chars' => array('letter', 'digit'),
        ),
    ),
    'filter' => array(
        'snowball' => array(
            'type' => 'snowball',
            'language' => 'French',
        ),
        'elision' => array(
            'type' => 'elision',
            'articles' => array('l', 'm', 't', 'qu', 'n', 's', 'j', 'd'),
        ),
        'stopwords' => array(
            'type' => 'stop',
            'stopwords' => array('_french_'),
            'ignore_case' => true,
        ),
        'worddelimiter' => array(
            'type' => 'word_delimiter',
        ),
        'synonym' => array(
            'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
            'type' => 'synonym',
            'synonyms_path' => sfConfig::get('app_elasticsearch_path_synonym'),
            'ignore_case' => true,
        ),
    ),
),
```

The **synonyms file** contain a line with "**CDD,Contrat à Durée Déterminée**".

And here, a part of **my index mapping** :

```
{
   "clic": {
      "mappings": {
         "idea": {
            "properties": {
               "expected_benefits": {
                  "properties": {
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "searchAnalyzer",
                        "include_in_all": true
                     }
                     ...
                  }
               },
               "initial_situation": {
                  "properties": {
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "searchAnalyzer",
                        "include_in_all": true
                     }
                     ...
                  }
               },
               "proposed_solution": {
                  "properties": {
                     "search": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "searchAnalyzer",
                        "include_in_all": true
                     }
                     ...
                  }
               },
               "title": {
                  "properties": {
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "searchAnalyzer",
                        "include_in_all": true
                     },
                     ...
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

A document sample :

```
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.030160192,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "clic",
            "_type": "idea",
            "_id": "3863",
            "_score": 0.030160192,
            "_source": {
               "id": "3863",
               "title": {
                  "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod",
                  ...
               },
               "initial_situation": {
                  "search": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                  ...
               },
               "proposed_solution": {
                  "search": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                  quis nostrud contrat à durée déterminée, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim",
                  ...
               },
               "expected_benefits": {
                  "search": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\r\n",
                  ...
               },
               ...
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When I use the **analyze API** like this : 
    GET /clic/_analyze?analyzer=searchAnalyzer&text=cdd

It output the **correct synonym** :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "cdd",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "contrat à durée déterminée",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

So far, it seems to be correct for me. 
In addition, when I use the **validate API** for explaining my query like this :

```
GET clic/idea/_validate/query?explain
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "multi_match": {
                        "query": "cdd",
                        "type": "cross_fields",
                        "fields": [
                           "title.name^3",
                           "initial_situation.search^3",
                           "proposed_solution.search^3",
                           "expected_benefits.search^3"
                        ],
                        "operator": "and",
                        "analyzer": "searchAnalyzer"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It output :

```
{
   "valid": true,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "explanations": [
      {
            "index": "clic",
            "valid": true,
            "explanation": "filtered((
                blended(terms: [proposed_solution.search:cdd, title.name:cdd, expected_benefits.search:cdd, initial_situation.search:cdd]) 
                blended(terms: [proposed_solution.search:contrat à durée déterminée, title.name:contrat à durée déterminée, expected_benefits.search:contrat à durée déterminée, initial_situation.search:contrat à durée déterminée])
            ))
            ->cache(_type:idea)"
      }
   ]
}
```

From what I understood, ES search both "cdd" and "contrat à durée déterminée" in all fiels that I mentionned. Thus, it should find document containing "cdd" or "contrat à durée déterminée".
But it's not the case. When I **do a post search with the same query, it hits 0 result**.

I hope I was clear in my explanations. Any help will be appreciated :) Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide the JSON mapping as well as a sample document so it's easier to reproduce your case?

Comment: Hi @Val, I update my question with your request. Thanks